# Terminal recognises the environment but the editor does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have installed the packages torch and numpy in my gcn env and when I run the program it is running without any errors, But the editor window is not recognizing the env hence showing two problems.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89WQi.png)

I am new to vsc please help me out

Comment: Configure your editor to use the same python executable as you do for your applications. On windows `ctrl+shift+P` > select python interpreter.

Comment: I have done this, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

> when I run the program it is running without any errors

If this is not a problem with the interpreter, you can try to search for **Python.Analysis.extraPath** in Settings.

[image]

This may be that Pylance cannot find your python environment package correctly. We have to add the path manually.

For example,

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```